# Создание статической круговой диаграммы с помощью CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

Я пытаюсь создать круговую диаграмму, используя CSS и HTML. Я бы просто отображал несколько статических чисел, поэтому я стараюсь сделать его относительно простым и не использовать анимацию.

В настоящее время я сталкиваюсь с препятствием на пути к созданию желаемого образа. Приведенный ниже фрагмент кода работает именно так, как я хотел бы, проблема в том, что `conic-gradient` не поддерживается в firefox и Internet Explorer, что будет проблемой в этом проекте.

```css
.progress-circle {
  --d: 50px;
  --color: #002F65;
  --progress: 40;
  border-radius: var(--d);
  height: var(--d);
  width: var(--d);
  background: conic-gradient( var(--color) calc(calc(var(--progress) / 100) * 360deg), transparent calc(calc(var(--progress) / 100) * 360deg));
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-circle"></div>
```

Я искал альтернативу, похожую на приведенный выше пример, который привел меня к этой статье: [designing simple pie charts with css](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/07/designing-simple-pie-charts-with-css/)

Моя проблема в том, что способ расчета процентного роста круговой диаграммы, похоже, несовместим с тем, что я пытаюсь достичь. как это определено преобразованием: повернуть (.1turn);
Мой главный вопрос, можно ли сделать конический градиент совместимым с другими браузерами? Если нет, то как лучше всего подойти к созданию круговой диаграммы с помощью CSS, чтобы она напоминала первый пример?

Для контекста я буду передавать данные из массива, чтобы определить процентную долю круговой диаграммы.

```css
.pie {
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: yellowgreen;
  background-image:
  linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, #655 0);
}

.pie::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin-left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 100% 100% 0 / 50%;
  background: #655;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: rotate(.1turn);
}
```

```html
<div class="pie"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Creating a static pie chart with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62924550/7394871) от участника  [@stepheniok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13501289/stepheniok).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62924550/7394871

Comment: На данный момент, актуально только для IE. Да и на дату оригинала вопроса, `conic-gradient` уже работал в FF под флагом. Может быть полезно для WinXP в связке со старыми браузерами.

Answer (score 3):

Вот идея, основанная на [этом предыдущем ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52205730/8620333)

```css
.box {
  /* percentage to degree
    --s:0 for [0% 50%]
    --s:1 for [50% 100%]
   */
  --v:calc( ((18/5) * var(--p) - 90)*1deg);

  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:
    linear-gradient(var(--v), yellowgreen 50%,transparent 0) 0 /calc((1 - var(--s))*100%),
    linear-gradient(var(--v), transparent 50%,#655        0) 0 /calc(var(--s)*100%),
    linear-gradient(to right, yellowgreen 50%,#655 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--p:5;--s:0"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:20;--s:0"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:50;--s:0"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:70;--s:1"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:95;--s:1"></div>
```

Мы можем оптимизировать код с помощью `min()` и сохранить использование только одной переменной, но вам нужно обратить внимание на поддержку: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-math-functions

```css
.box {
  /* percentage to degree  */
  --v:calc( ((18/5) * var(--p) - 90)*1deg);

  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:
    linear-gradient(var(--v), yellowgreen 50%,transparent 0) 0 /min(100%,(50 - var(--p))*100%),
    linear-gradient(var(--v), transparent 50%,#655        0) 0 /min(100%,(var(--p) - 50)*100%),
    linear-gradient(to right, yellowgreen 50%,#655 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--p:5;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:20;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:50;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:70;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:95;"></div>
```

Еще одна идея с использованием псевдоэлемента с большей поддержкой:

```css
.box {
  /* percentage to degree  */
  --v: calc( ((18/5) * var(--p) - 180)*1deg);
  
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, yellowgreen 50%, #655 0);
}

.box::before,
.box::after {
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  padding-top:100%;
  transform: rotate(var(--v));
}

.box::before {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(yellowgreen 0 0) 
    0 / calc((50 - var(--p))*1%);
  transform-origin: right;
}

.box::after {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#655 0 0)       
    0 / calc((var(--p) - 50)*1%);
  transform-origin: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--p:5;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:20;width:150px;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:50;width:120px;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:70;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:95;width:80px;"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62924929/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

### CSS решение

Основано на изменении параметров атрибута `stroke-dasharray`

Чтобы установить нужные значения атрибута в соответствии с  углом открытия сектора, нужно узнать полную длину окружности при выбранном радиусе.
Допустим радиус равен `50px`

```
let radius = 50;
 let circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;
 console.log(circumference );
```

Полная длина окружности `circumference ~=314px`

Например, чтобы нарисовать сегмент равный четверти круга:

вычисляем длину черты: `314 * 0.25 = 78.5px`
Длина пробела :  `314 * 0.75 = 235.5px`

Итого для значения `stroke-dasharray="78.5, 235.5"`

Аналогичным образом установлены параметры stroke-dasharray для другиx углов секторов

```css
circle {
fill:#665555;
} 
#p15,#p90,#p180,#p270 {
fill:none;
stroke:#9ACD32;
stroke-width:100;
}
#p15 {
stroke-dasharray:15.7,298.3;
}
#p90 {
stroke-dasharray:78.5,235.5;
}
#p180 {
stroke-dasharray:157,157;
}
#p270 {
stroke-dasharray:235.5,78.5;
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid">
   <circle id="bg" r="100" cx="100" cy="100"  />  
       
   <path id="p15"    d="M100,50A50,50 0 0 1 100,150A50,50 0 0 1 100,50">
  </path>
</svg>   
           <!-- 90deg -->
   <svg width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid">
       <circle  r="100" cx="100" cy="100" />  
            
       <path id="p90"  stroke-dasharray="78.5,235.5"  d="M100,50A50,50 0 0 1 100,150A50,50 0 0 1 100,50">
       </path>
   </svg> 
           <!-- 180deg -->
   <svg width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid">
       <circle  r="100" cx="100" cy="100"  />  
            
       <path id="p180"  d="M100,50A50,50 0 0 1 100,150A50,50 0 0 1 100,50">
       </path>
   </svg>   
           <!-- 270deg -->
<svg width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid">
       <circle  r="100" cx="100" cy="100"  />  
            
       <path id="p270"    d="M100,50A50,50 0 0 1 100,150A50,50 0 0 1 100,50">
       </path>
</svg>    
  
  
<script>
 let radius = 50;
 let circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;
 console.log(circumference ); 
 </script>
```

### SVG решение

Как и в примере `решения CSS` используется изменение атрибутов `stroke-dasharray`

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <circle id="bg" r="100" cx="100" cy="100"  fill="#665555"/> 
 
  <path stroke-dasharray="300 14" stroke-dashoffset="300" d="M100,50A50,50 0 0 1 100,150A50,50 0 0 1 100,50" id="p1" 
     r="50" cx="100" cy="100" stroke="#9ACD32" stroke-width="100" fill="none"  >
  </path>
 </svg>
   <svg width="200" height="200">
      <circle  r="100" cx="100" cy="100"  fill="#665555"/> 
          <path stroke-dasharray="235.5 78.5" stroke-dashoffset="235.5" d="M100,50A50,50 0 0 1 100,150A50,50 0 0 1 100,50" stroke="#9ACD32" stroke-width="100" fill="none" > 
          </path>
   </svg> 
<svg width="200" height="200">
      <circle id="bg" r="100" cx="100" cy="100"  fill="#665555"/> 
          <path stroke-dasharray="157 157" stroke-dashoffset="157" d="M100,50A50,50 0 0 1 100,150A50,50 0 0 1 100,50"  stroke="#9ACD32" stroke-width="100" fill="none"  >
      </path>
</svg>  
    <svg width="200" height="200">
      <circle id="bg" r="100" cx="100" cy="100"  fill="#665555"/> 
          <path stroke-dasharray="78.5 235.5" stroke-dashoffset="78.5" d="M100,50A50,50 0 0 1 100,150A50,50 0 0 1 100,50"  stroke="#9ACD32" stroke-width="100" fill="none"  >
      </path>
    </svg>
```

### Пример интерактивного  изменения угла сектора

> Для контекста я буду передавать данные из массива, чтобы определить
> процентную долю круговой диаграммы.

С помощью `input` и `JS` смоделирован этот процесс:

1. Вывод процентов заполнения диаграммы

```js
let circumference = 50 * 2 * Math.PI,
 input = document.querySelector("[type='range']"),
 txt = document.querySelector("#txt1");

input.addEventListener("input",()=>{  
  pieChart();  
})

window.addEventListener("load",()=>{  
  pieChart();  
})

function pieChart(){
  let val = Number(input.value);
  let dash = circumference * val / 100;
  let gap = circumference - dash;
  p15.style.strokeDasharray = dash + " " + gap
txt.innerHTML = (val + '%'); 
}
```

```html
<div><input id="size" step="1" type="range" min="0" max = "100" value="0" /></div>
<svg width="200" height="200" >
   <circle id="bg" r="100" cx="100" cy="100"  fill="#665555"/>  
       
   <path id="p15"  stroke-dasharray="15.7,298.3"  d="M100,50A50,50 0 0 1 100,150A50,50 0 0 1 100,50" id="p1" fill="none" stroke="#9ACD32" stroke-width="100" >
  </path> 
   <text id="txt1" y="60%" x="50%"  text-anchor="middle" font-size="32px" fill="white">0</text>
</svg>
```

2. Вывод угла заполнения диаграммы

```js
let circumference = 50 * 2 * Math.PI,
 input = document.querySelector("[type='range']"),
 txt = document.querySelector("#txt1");

input.addEventListener("input",()=>{  
  pieChart();  
})

window.addEventListener("load",()=>{  
  pieChart();  
})

function pieChart(){
  let val = Number(input.value);
  let dash = circumference * val / 360;
  let gap = circumference - dash;
  p15.style.strokeDasharray = dash + " " + gap
txt.innerHTML = (val); 
}
```

```html
<div><input id="size" step="1" type="range" min="0" max = "360" value="0" /></div>
<svg width="200" height="200" >
   <circle id="bg" r="100" cx="100" cy="100"  fill="#665555"/>  
       
   <path id="p15"  stroke-dasharray="15.7,298.3"  d="M100,50A50,50 0 0 1 100,150A50,50 0 0 1 100,50" id="p1" fill="none" stroke="#9ACD32" stroke-width="100" >
  </path> 
   <text id="txt1" y="60%" x="50%"  text-anchor="middle" font-size="32px" fill="white">0</text>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67956460/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>